# Silverlight Browser Application Capabilities for OSX

Tags: silverlight, macos, .net-4.0, cross-browser

My company has developed a .net 4 WPF application that connects to our manufacturing devices over a local network and controls them, in addition to processing image data and outputting it to these devices from the windows desktop.  I have been tasked with porting a bare bones version of this to mac. My options are mono for mac or a browser based SilverLight application.

What is the feasibility of a browser based app that will essentially

-scan the local network for our devices and send commands to the chosen device

-accept images from the local machine, uploading them to our server for processing. We would then send the processed data back for output to the local device and display the final image in the browser.

I'm aware that SilverLight 4 Elevated Privileges allow connection across a domain without port number limitations. However I am unsure about scanning a network from a silverlight app running in safari.

Comment: The future of Silverlight, and thus its viability as a platform, is in serious question. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/11/10/microsoft_killing_silverlight_rumours/ Besides which, the features you describe don't sound at all like a good fit for a browser-based app.  Given your choices, Mono sounds like the safer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -accept images from the local machine, uploading them to our server for processing. We would then send the processed data back for output
>   to the local device and display the final image in the browser.

Silverlight app can't access files from local machine without user interaction. OpenFileDialog class can't be user initiated. you have to select files from local machine to upload to some service.

> -scan the local network for our devices and send commands to the chosen device

as far as scaning local network is concerned, silverlight don't offer TCP ping. if your devices offer some interface using http you might be able to connection and send commands to devices using WebClient.

Further last but not the least silverlight is not full supported in MAC OS described by microsoft. so you might face weird issue that will remain unfixed. Check System Requirement here http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx

Regards.